# How to UPDATE one to many (hasMany) relation in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

Well, I am using Laravel 5.4 and reached in a situation where I need to update one to many (hasMany) relation ship.
I have a `products` table and a `product_images` table. Below is my relation definition in each model.

```
//Product.php
public function productImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductImage');
}

//ProductImage.php
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

I am giving a form interface to update existing product. In that I have 4 optional file upload input html tag for updating or adding (new) images for the product. Remember all these 4 image upload is optional.

So my question is what is the best approach(laravel way) to

1. update existing entries in `product_images` table
2. add new one if provided
3. delete existing if it is removed

I know the `attach` or `detach` method (`sync`) to remove all and then add the provided one. But I want to maintain the id if we are replacing any existing image.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but here's an answer.

**1 and 2** - Laravel's updateOrCreate() method will update existing records and insert new records if an existing image ID is not provided. See "updateOrCreate" under [Eloquent ORM's Update documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates).

```
$images = App\ProductImage::updateOrCreate(
    ['id' => $id],
    ['field1' => $field1, 'field2' => $field2]
);
```

**3** - To delete, add a delete checkbox to your form which passes target image IDs as an array...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="imgsToDelete[]" value="{{$product->image->id}}">
<label>Delete</label>
```

...then, in your product update method, simply pass the field array to Eloquent's destroy() method.

```
$imgsToDelete = $request->get('imgsToDelete');
ProductImage::destroy($imgsToDelete);
```

Don't forget to delete stored images from the file system!